# need to do a computation for the next 120 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a ROW function, IF statement, INDIRECT statement, or another function (no VBA or macros please) that will allow me to do a computation for the next 120 rows?  Here's why I need it:

I have a budget spreadsheet that accounts for all sorts of potential expenses over many years to come, with money coming in and going out.  When my checking balance gets to zero, I can pull money from an equity loan (I choose the amount) and add it back in to my checking account.  From this point on, however, I need the spreadsheet to remove the monthly payments (I assuming equal equal payments for simplicity's sake) for 120 months.  I just don't know how to tell it to remove those monthly payments for only 120 months and then stop.  ??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you can show a screenshot of your account, and we can suggest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel has both a =ROW function and an =IF function. So you could do something like =IF(ROW() - ROW(CELLWHERELOANTAKEN) <= 120, SUBTRACTPAYMENT,)

This requires that you know the cell address of where a loan was taken. You can accomplish that by adding a column that is a 0 or 1. 0 if a loan wasn't taken that month and a 1 if a loan was taken (1 if balance is 0, 0 if positive)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you have a separate column to flag the monthly payment and remove them through a `SUMIF` instead?